# multipart boundary not found - aws api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have created AWS API-Gateway and I am trying to upload an image using Postman but I received an error of **Multipart: boundary not found.**

I have tried below solution for this issue whereas I created model for API as follows:

```
Model name: fileupload
Content type: image/png

Model schema:
{
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title": "UserAccountUpdate",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
   "user": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
          "avatar": { "type": "string" },
          "username": { "type": "string" }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

But, this didn't worked.

I expect my image to get uploaded but it receives an error of **Multipart: boundary not found.**. Please Help me to resolve this issue, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the API Gateway settings tab for your API and add "multipart/form-data" to the "binary media types" section:

### [image]

You have to use HTTP Proxy integration and for Content Handling , choose Passthrough.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the reply, I have tried this solution but same error came again. Is there any problem with my model schema code or I am missing something major? Please answer :)

Comment: Try removing the content-type header, I've heard it may cause trouble

Comment: sorry for late reply! I have tried removing header but it's not working as well, producing same error to me.

Comment: I am uploading a file with multipart/formdata and I don't use any model for it, since in content handling it is set as Passthrough, it passes it directly to the endpoint. Try removing the model

Comment: Hey! Thanks this was useful. I figured out that API Gateway was removing multipart boundary (used for separate name/value parts) that is part of Content-type header. The solution was allow it to passthrough using proxy integration. *Remove this header isn´t helpful, at least you have backend control and know how to manage the data.

Comment: This method is working for me

Answer (score 1):

I have added  "Content-Type:method.request.header.Content-Type" in http headers. Then it is working.[image]